How do we know that the type of an object is Dictionary (of anything,anything)
I tried this code. ChatGPT suggested that.
Function IsDictionary(value As Object) As Boolean
    ' Get the type of the value
    Dim valueType = value.GetType()

    ' Check if the type is a generic type and if it's a Dictionary
    If valueType.IsGenericType Then
        ' Get the generic type definition
        Dim genericTypeDef = valueType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()

        ' Check if it's a Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
        If genericTypeDef Is GetType(Dictionary(Of Object, Object)) Then
            ' It's a Dictionary, but we don't know the types of the keys and values
            Return True
        End If
    End If

    Return False
End Function

I did a bit testing
    Dim dict1 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {{"key1", 1}, {"key2", 2}}
    Dim dict2 As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) From {{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}}
    Dim notADictionary As New List(Of String) From {"item1", "item2"}
    Dim a = False
    a = IsDictionary(dict1)
    a = IsDictionary(dict2)
    a = IsDictionary(notADictionary)

In all cases a is false.
The issue is that Dictionary(Of Integer, String) is not necessarily the same with Dictionary(Of Object, Object)
Chatgpt can't figure this out either.
So I asked here.
Basically it's useful if I want to compare CONTENT of two dictionaries. Each of the dictionary is equal if the content is the same. However, the type of dictionaries may not be exactly the same.
For example, one of them or one of the value of both of them may differ. One maybe dictionary(of string, object) and another will be dictionary(of string, string). As long as they all contain string, I would want to see this as same.
How can I do so in vb.net
In python I can just do dict1 == dict2

You can create an open generic type by leaving the type name empty as in GetType(Dictionary(Of , )).
Function IsDictionary(value As Object) As Boolean
    Dim valueType = value.GetType()

    If valueType.IsGenericType Then
        Dim genericTypeDef = valueType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()

        Return genericTypeDef Is GetType(Dictionary(Of , ))
    End If

    Return False
End Function

The test ...
Dim openGenericType As Type = GetType(Dictionary(Of , ))
Console.WriteLine(openGenericType)
Console.WriteLine()

Dim dict1 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {{"key1", 1}, {"key2", 2}}
Dim dict2 As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) From {{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}}
Dim notADictionary As New List(Of String) From {"item1", "item2"}
Console.WriteLine(IsDictionary(dict1))
Console.WriteLine(IsDictionary(dict2))
Console.WriteLine(IsDictionary(notADictionary))

...prints
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue]

True
True
False

Note that you cannot declare a variable with Dim dict As Dictionary(Of , ), you can only use the open generic type in conjunction with GetType() to get a System.Type object.

Note also that you can simplify code like ...
If <Boolean Expression> Then
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If

or
If <Boolean Expression> Then
    Return True
End If
Return False

... and instead simply write
Return <Boolean Expression>

... because the Boolean expression itself yields the value True or False that you want to return.

While ChatGPT might point you into the right direction, it can't reason about the code. Today's AIs guess based on statistics and deliver results they believe are likely. Therefore, the code might be sub-optimal or even false. You are the one who has to contribute the intelligence. You cannot delegate it to the AI.

Wow. I didn't know this. This is why sometimes we need super programmers like you. Most easy question can go to chatgpt though

Any source? Like where in the documentation say we can do this?

See How to: Examine and instantiate generic types with reflection (you can switch the code examples between C#, VB and C++). However, I did not find a good documentation in VB specific tutorials or references.
